# How to choose the error code for an error?

Tags: c

Suppose I am asked to output an error if a certain file exist.
for example

I am asked to create a file called "del.txt", however, I have to check if such file exist first, and if it does I have to output an error of code 2.

So I know I have to use the O_EXCL to check if the file exist or not, and if it does I should give an error. however the error code is undefined, but I want to set it to 2.

Any idea how?

Here is my current code:

```
    char *filename = "del.txt";
    int n;
    if((n = open(filename, O_EXCL) > 0){
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    };
```

I am currently getting this:

```
del.txt: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: Do you know what `exit(1)` means?

Comment: @TomKarzes, no, you did not get what I meant, perhaps I was not clear enough. I just wanted to understand how to induce an error because a file exist, and PSkocik gave me the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error check should be `< 0`, not `> 0`, the flags are missing an access mode (`O_RDONLY/O_WRONLY/O_RDWR`), and an `O_CREAT` needs to be used with `O_EXCL` (or else, POSIX says, the behavior is undefiend).

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    char const *filename = "del.txt";
    int n;
    if((n = open(filename, O_RDONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL) < 0)){
        perror(filename);
        exit(1);
    };
}
```